# Pytest errors with flask

Tags: python, flask, pytest

I've been trying to add unit tests to my Flask application. I am using the application factory pattern.
I have been using https://github.com/cookiecutter-flask as a reference, and I believe I have implemented the tests following their implementation. I am getting some errors when running `py.test` that I do not understand how to fix, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have included what I thought were relevant parts of my code below:

**tests/conftest.py**

```
import pytest
from webtest import TestApp
from urlshort import create_app
from urlshort.models import Link
from urlshort.models import db as _db

@pytest.fixture
def app():
    """Create application for the tests."""
    _app = create_app(testing=True)

    ctx = _app.test_request_context()
    ctx.push()
    yield _app
    ctx.pop()


@pytest.fixture
def testapp(app):
    """Create Webtest app."""
    return TestApp(app)


@pytest.fixture
def db(app):
    """Create database for the tests."""
    _db.app = app
    with app.app_context():
        _db.create_all()

    yield _db

    _db.session.close()
    _db.drop_all()


@pytest.fixture
def link(db):
    """Create a link for the tests."""
    link = Link(long='https://example.com/', short='3')
    db.session.add(link)
    return link
```

**tests/test_forms.py**

```
from urlshort.forms import URLForm, UnshortenForm
from urlshort.strings import Strings

class TestURLForm:
    """URLForm tests"""

    def test_inject_strings(self, testapp):
        """Tests if the inject_strings() context processor works as expected"""
        response = self.testapp.post('/', data=dict(
            url='notaurl'
        ), follow_redirects = True)
        assert Strings.strings['URLValidationError'].encode() in response.data

    def test_invalid_link(self):
        """Invalid link"""
        form = URLForm(url='notaurl')
        assert form.validate() is False
```

Here is my create_app if it is any help:

**urlshort/__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask

from config import Config, TestConfig
from urlshort.models import db


def create_app(testing=False):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    if testing:
        app.config.from_object(TestConfig)
    else:
        app.config.from_object(Config)

    db.init_app(app)

    from urlshort.routes import shortener

    app.register_blueprint(shortener)
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()

    app.shell_context_processor(shell_context)

    return app


def shell_context():
    """Shell context objects."""
    return {"db": db}
```

Here is the relevant output for pytest:

```
============================================================================================ short test summary info ============================================================================================
FAILED tests/test_forms.py::TestURLForm::test_invalid_link - RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
```

The tests should be running with test_request_context(). I don't know how to debug this, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I managed to fix the first error, I called self.testapp instead of testapp. The second error persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem, the solution was to pass app to test_invalid_link:

```
    def test_invalid_link(self, app):
        """Invalid link"""
        form = URLForm(url='notaurl')
        assert form.validate() is False
```

So that it actually gets the application context.